# Clarification about Quotient Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

The question given to me is:

Does there exist a vector space $V$ which has a nonzero subspace $U$ such that
$V /U \cong V$ ? Provide an example or a proof that no such $V /U$ exists.

Intuitively, I would have guessed such a Quotient Space does exist... of course, I'm wrong but don't see why.

Let V be the vector Space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let U be the subspace $ \mathbb{R} $ of $V$.

We know $V/U = \left \{ v+U : v \in V \right \}$

So for every vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we add all vectors of $\mathbb{R}$ to this vector, creating a bunch of vector spaces whose union is still identical to $\mathbb{R}^2$, right?

since $\forall \space w \in (v+U) $ we have that $w \in V$, $\forall \space v  \in V$.

And the same applies in the reverse order if we consider the union of all $(v + U)$.

Hence the Quotient Space is Isomorphic with $V$.

It may be that my understanding of Vector Spaces is completely wrong, in which case I would appreciate if someone could explain to me intuitively where I have gone off track.

I would prefer the explanation to be as intuitive as possible, rigorous mathematical proofs could confuse me more.

Thans for any help !

Comment: "Hence the vector space is isomorphic with V" - huh? How does that follow? By the way, you won't be able to do this problem with finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Quotient Space, sorry, edited

Comment: I knew you were talking about the quotient space. I was pointing out your argument was a non sequitur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are examples, but not finite dimensional ones.

If $V$ is finite dimensional, the rank-nullity theorem applied to the linear map $V\to V/U$ tells you that
$$
\dim V=\dim V/U+\dim U
$$
because $U$ is the kernel of that map. Thus, if $U\ne\{0\}$, we get that $\dim V/U<\dim V$, so $V/U$ cannot be isomorphic to $V$.

You can find examples with the vector space $\mathcal{P}$ of polynomials, which is not finite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: Isn't V a finite-dimesnional vector space in my example though?

Comment: @GregoryPeck Yes, but your argument is wrong. Each $v+U$ is a single object in $V/U$, and $v_1+U=v_2+U$ whenever $v_1-v_2\in U$: so two distinct elements of $V$ can determine the same element in $V/U$..

Comment: Cool, thanks!!!